# How to split dataframe column by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have dataset which contains 6.2M records. When iam splitting it by grouping, it looses about 1.2M records. This is fraction of data set:

```
VendorID | tpep_pickup_datetime | tpep_dropoff_datetime | passenger_count |
1        | 2020-01-01 00:28:15  | 2020-01-01 00:33:03   |  1.0  
1        | 2020-01-01 00:35:39  | 2020-01-01 00:43:04   |  1.0  
..       |....................  | ...................   |  ...
1        | 2020-01-31 00:47:41  | 2020-01-31 00:53:52   |  1.0  
1        | 2020-01-31 00:55:23  | 2020-01-31 01:00:14   |  1.0  
2        | 2020-01-31 00:01:58  | 2020-01-31 00:04:16   |  1.0
```

I need to split it in column `tpep_dropoff_datetime`  by days. This is code i use to do that, but as i mentioned before, it's not working properly.

```
for date, g in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['tpep_dropoff_datetime']).dt.normalize().astype(str)):
    g.to_csv(f'{date}.csv', index=False)
```

Any ideas, how to split dataframe ?

Comment: Why does the format from the column `tpep_pickup_datetime` (`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`) is different from the column `tpep_dropoff_datetime` (`%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S`)?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this, though I believe it might not be the best way around (Pandas might have a better way for doing this).

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ["VendorID", "tpep_pickup_datetime", "tpep_dropoff_datetime", "passenger_count"]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, "2020-01-01 00:28:15", "2020-01-01 00:33:03", 1.0],
     [1, "2020-01-01 00:35:39", "2020-01-01 00:43:04", 1.0],
     [1, "2020-01-31 00:47:41", "2020-01-31 00:53:52", 1.0],
     [1, "2020-01-31 00:55:23", "2020-01-31 01:00:14", 1.0],
    ],
    columns=cols,
)
# I do this because of the example the date is a string and I'm changing it to datetime.
# This might not be necesary, depends on your data.
df["tpep_dropoff_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df['tpep_dropoff_datetime'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# Create a new column named "my_date" which
# will contains the date from the column "tpep_dropoff_datetime"
df["my_date"] = df["tpep_dropoff_datetime"].dt.date

# Now we group by date al the rows, and copy the ones according to their index
for date, indexes in df.groupby('my_date').groups.items():
    print(f"date: {date}")
    print(f"indexes: {indexes}")
    # Copying the rows I want according to the index
    aux_df = df.loc[indexes]
    print(aux_df)
    # Exporting to csv only the columns I want
    aux_df.to_csv(f"{date}.csv", columns=cols, index=False)
```

The output are the files and this one in the console:

```
date: 2020-01-01
indexes: Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
   VendorID tpep_pickup_datetime tpep_dropoff_datetime  passenger_count     my_date
0         1  2020-01-01 00:28:15   2020-01-01 00:33:03              1.0  2020-01-01
1         1  2020-01-01 00:35:39   2020-01-01 00:43:04              1.0  2020-01-01
date: 2020-01-31
indexes: Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64')
   VendorID tpep_pickup_datetime tpep_dropoff_datetime  passenger_count     my_date
2         1  2020-01-31 00:47:41   2020-01-31 00:53:52              1.0  2020-01-31
3         1  2020-01-31 00:55:23   2020-01-31 01:00:14              1.0  2020-01-31
```

With this at least I would be sure that I get the date right, but probably is not the best in efficiency

Comment: I see, where problem was. It's because 'DtypeWarning'. Maybe have any ideas, how i can change dtypes when exporting ?

Comment: Which row is causing this? If it is the one with datetime you can use the parameter `date_format` from `to_csv` to indicate it. Read more about `to_csv` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). If it's another column fault, I guess you could change it with something like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/change-data-type-for-one-or-more-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/) before using `to_csv`.

Comment: Well, dataset, which iam using is much bigger, than showed here, its just a fragment :) Iam trying to change that dtype, which have int and str in itself. But after spliting, its still there.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that the data is huge. Mmm maybe [conver_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) ?